# when I update a mongodb collection ,can I search on the collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I know when update operator will lock collection,but I want to know concurrent search operator can be not affected?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question had been asked before:
[MongoDB :are reads/writes to database concurrent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828875/mongodb-are-reads-writes-to-database-concurrent)

MongoDB used to have a global write lock which seems to have been removed lately as per this link:
http://blog.serverdensity.com/2012/05/23/goodbye-global-lock-mongodb-2-0-vs-2-2/
Also worth reading is this, although it's an older link:
http://blog.pythonisito.com/2011/12/mongodbs-write-lock.html